# Transparent proxy on a Siemens router

Tags: networking, router, proxy

I would like to install a transparent proxy with content filtering (such as Squid) on my Siemens ADSL SL2-141 router, such that all requests in my home network are automatically routed through the proxy, without having to install the proxy on each computer and each browser.

I looked in the API of the router and haven't found any setting that looks like "proxy". Here is the list of commands I see when I telnet into the router:

```
logout
reboot
adsl
atm
brctl
cat
ddns
df
dumpcfg
echo
ifconfig
kill
arp
defaultgateway
dhcpserver
dns
lan
passwd
ppp
remoteaccess
localaccess
restoredefault
route
save
swversion
wan
ping
ps
pwd
sntp
sysinfo
tftp
wlctl
wireless
gpio
```

Is there maybe another name/another way to set a proxy on a router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That router only has support for IGMP Proxy/Snoop; you cannot implement a transparent proxy like Squid in that device running default firmware.

You could run Squid (or other ones) if you flash it with OpenWRT

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/proxy.overview

Please consider that flashing your router with non official firmware is a risky operation that might lead to brick your device, void your warranty, etc. Please carefully read before attempting this.